# How to actively grep log for the last 15 seconds for a phrase?

Tags: shell-script, grep, tail

I have this bash script and inside the script, I am trying to grep a log for the words "status change" and then after I find the most recent line that contains the words "status change" (aka the most recent status change), I grep that line for the word "Backup".

The problem is that I am currently putting it to sleep for 15 seconds first so the log has time to be updated of the most recent status change but I want a better solution for this.

I want it to actively check for the status and report a failure only after 15 seconds. If possible, I would like to only replace my first 2 lines of code because I plan on making other modifications to the rest. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Here is what I currently have:

```
    sleep 15
    ssh server_one@$1 "grep 'status change' /apps/tests/$2 | tail -1 | grep 'Backup'"
    Output=$?
    if [[ ${Output} -ne 1 ]] ; then
            echo "Pass: It is Backup"
            echo "Pass: It is Backup"  >> $REPORT 
    else
            echo "Fail: It is not Backup"
            echo "Fail: It is not Backup" >> $REPORT
    fi
```

Comment: The text of the question talks about looking for the word `active`.  The code looks for the word `Backup`.  Which is it?

Comment: The two most obvious solutions that occur to me are: 1. if the remote system is running linux, use `inotifywait` from the `inotify-tools` package; and 2. use the `perl` `File::Tail` module.  Both methods avoid any need to sleep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer intended for original version of question**

For your one command, replacing the grep-tail-grep-if commands, try:

```
awk '/status change/{last=$0} END{printf "It is %sBackup\n",(last~/Active/?"":"not ")}' "/apps/tests/$2"
```

How it works:

- `/status change/{last=$0}`

  Every time that a line containing `status change` is found, it is saved in the variable `last`.
- `END{printf "It is %sBackup\n",(last~/Active/?"":"not ")}`

  This is executed after we have finished reading the file. At that time, `last` will contain the contents of the last line that contained `status change`.  If that line also contains `Active`, then we print `It is Backup`.  Otherwise, we print `It is not Backup`.

  The presence or absence of the word `not` is controlled by the somewhat complex looking ternary statement: `(last~/Active/?"":"not ")`.  This statement just checks to see if `last~/Active/` is true (meaning the line last contains `Active`).  If it does, the ternary statement returns the empty string `""`.  If it does not, it returns the string `"not "`.

#### Continuous monitoring

To monitor continuously:

```
ssh "server_one@$1" tail -f "/apps/tests/$2" | awk '/status change/{printf "It is %sBackup\n",($0~/Backup/?"":"not ")}'
```

Comment: thank you for your help! instead of replacing my entire scripts above, would it be possible to only modify the line 'ssh server_one@$1 "grep 'status change' /apps/tests/$2 | tail -1 | grep 'Backup'" '? I am planning to modify the code so it becomes 'echo "Pass: $1: $2 is Backup"
echo "Pass: $1: $2 is Backup"  >> $REPORT '
In addition, I meant to say to grep for the word "Backup" instead of "active" so sorry about that.

Comment: In addition, I was wondering where in the code you wait until 15 seconds and if you still can't find it, you report it to not be backup?

Comment: @saraberry OK.  I added a section that avoids the 15 seconds problem and monitors continuously.